# Prometheus and cadvisor disk usage for containers not showing

Tags: prometheus, dcos, cadvisor

I cannot find any disk usage traces in Prometheus of the containers I'm monitoring with cadvior. All of them have a value of 0. The only ones that have values are the ones with id="/".

[image]

All the non-root entries are 0. I checked with the query

```
changes(container_fs_usage_bytes{id!="/"}[60m] offset 215h)
```

There are no changes, it's always 0. I'm running my containers on CentOS 7.3 and they are managed by a DCOS cluster. I launch the cadvisor instances with the command:

```
sudo docker run --volume=/:/rootfs:ro --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro --volume=/cgroup:/cgroup:ro --publish=8082:8080 --privileged=true --detach=true --name=cadvisor google/cadvisor:latest
```

So I can make sure that the proper permissions are set. Why can I see some kind of aggregated metric with the id="/" tag but I cannot see stats per container?

Answer (score 0):

You're only bind-mounting "/dev/disk" while you seem to be using the device mapper Docker storage driver, which relies on other locations under "dev" (such as "/dev/mapper" where virtual devices are exposed). Bind-mounting the whole "/dev" filesystem should fix your issue.

Comment: I changed --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro  to --volume=/dev:/dev:ro but still no results

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
sum(container_fs_writes_bytes_total{container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id=~".+", id=~"/docker/.*"}) by (container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name)
```